# AdonisJS - Cannot find module 'fs/promises'

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I had a problem creating an **AdonisJS** project due to the next error when I try to run the command `npm init adonis-ts-app@latest hello-world`:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that my **node** version was **12** so I update it to node **14** and that's works OK

*Note: I updated it via NVM because I need the node 12 version for other projects.*